# Обработка доменного имени заканчивающегося точкой

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Недавно обнаружил, что запрос `www.site.ru.` и `www.site.ru./` открывает `www.site.ru`.

Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить nginx что бы он обрабатывал "." в конце доменного имени и делал редирект на корень сайта?

Пробовал через `return 301` и через `location =/.`, но пока не работает.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/172999/

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё заработало.